# Start WinForms application from Windows Service

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services, windows-server-2008

I have a (3rd party) WinForms application that I need to keep alive 24/7 on a Windows Server. My first thought was to write a Windows Service that starts the application (using `System.Diagnostics.Process`) and restarts it if it should crash or the server is restarted.

Is this even possible? I need it to start even if no user is signed in on the server. Can an application with a user interface run when no one is logged in? If no, is there a workaround?

N.B. I don't need to interact with the application in any way, I just need to start it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to keep a form running 24/7? Here are some possibilities I can imagine.

1. You need a specific behavior to occur every so often.
2. It's opening a port that you want other applications to connect to.
3. You don't want employees to be able to exit the application.

If the answer is #3 then a Windows Service isn't the right answer and anything you try is just going to turn into a huge hack. If it's #1 or #2 you need to think about separating your single application into two.

For a recurring task the easiest solution would be to develop a console application and setting up a Task in the Windows Task Scheduler. This is much easier to manage and debug than a Windows Service. If you are trying to run a socket service of some kind the typical approach is to create an application with no GUI and the only way to access it is through a socket connection. If the WinForm closes the socket service keeps chugging away and the WinForm can grab the latest information when it is reopened.

Comment: The application is sort of a data collection platform. It collects data from multiple sources (tcp, rs232, etc) and saves it in a database. I don't have the source code to this application, so I can't manipulate it in any way, I can only start it. And I need to make sure that it is always running.

Comment: @Joel - Well you're up the creek then. Windows Services are not designed for Form based applications.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm realizing.... I was just hoping that there was a way to start an application without a user "assigned" to it

Comment: @Joel - Ideally you should hire someone to build the application and give you the source code.

Comment: If I had the time I would rewrite it myself. Unfortunately I don't... :)

Comment: do you have any idea of how something like this works? http://www.kwakkelflap.com/service.html

Comment: @Joel - Not really no. :(

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to think of a different approach. trying to show a GUI to user through windows service is not going to be a easy task, I came accross similar situation and finally i had to go for a different approach.

> **Why can't you directly show UI from Service** : This is due to some security implementation
>   went into windows OS with Windows Vista and later OS versions.
>   Microsoft disallowed windows services from *directly* interacting with
>   user desktop as it led to some [security flaw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatter_attack)

-

> I don't need to interact with the application in any way

if thats the case, I assume that application doesnt need any user interaction to continue its operation it will do its own ? if then you can even go for a `command prompt` exe.

> I need it to start even if no user is signed in on the server

I would strongly recommend you to go for [Windows Task Scheduler](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/12444-task-scheduler-create-new-task.html). Which will make your life much more easier. it doesnt require any user to manually start the program, It can start your progarm when computer starts/re-starts or even you can schedule to run your program on specific intervals. You can also check other good .net task scheduling libraries, [quartznet](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) is one of them.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But as I stated in the comments of the other answer, I don't have the source code of the application, so I can't make any changes to it. The problem with Windows Task Scheduler, as I see it, is that there is no way to monitor and detect if the application crashes and then restart it. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Joel You can set the time interval to start the application and also there is a property to set, where it will start the program only if its not runnig. so if the application crashes when the time interval ends and if the program is not running scheduler will start it again.