# Form created in Service not showing

Tags: c#, winforms, service

I created a `Service` in C#. I needed a GUI for configuration of the Service so I added a WinForms project to my solution. My plans was to create the Form in the Service and show it in the `OnStart()` Method of the Service. However, it won't show. The `WriteEntry()` Methods of the `EventLog` are all firing, so my code definitely is processed. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
public partial class UrlWatcherService : ServiceBase
{
    private UrlWatcherForm _urlwatcherform;
    private EventLog _eventLog;
    private string _eventLogName = "UrlWatcherEventLog";
    private string _eventLogSource = "UrlWatcherSource";

    public UrlWatcherService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadVariables();
    }

    public void OnDebug()
    {
        OnStart(null);
    }

    private void LoadVariables()
    {
        _urlwatcherform = new UrlWatcherForm();
        _eventLog = new EventLog();
        CanPauseAndContinue = true;

        if (!EventLog.SourceExists(_eventLogSource))
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(_eventLogSource, _eventLogName);

        _eventLog.Source = _eventLogSource;
        _eventLog.Log = _eventLogName;
        _eventLog.WriteEntry("Url Watcher Log Created", EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _eventLog.WriteEntry("Url Watcher Service Started", EventLogEntryType.Information);
        _urlwatcherform.Show();
        _eventLog.WriteEntry("Url Watcher Form Created", EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        _eventLog.WriteEntry("Url Watcher Service Paused", EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }

    protected override void OnContinue()
    {
        base.OnContinue();
        _eventLog.WriteEntry("Url Watcher Log Continued", EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _eventLog.WriteEntry("Url Watcher Service Stopped", EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }
}
```

```
public partial class UrlWatcherForm : Form
{
    public UrlWatcherForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void UrlWatcherGui_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormWindowState.Minimized == WindowState)
            Hide();
    }

    private void UrlWatcherGui_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        e.Cancel = true;
    }

    private void urlWatcherNofiyIcon_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Show();
    }
}
```

EDIT: To clarify, if I debug it like below, the Form shows. I can put the thread to sleep but that won't let me interact with the Form anymore. But the Form definitely shows, it's just in an unresponsive state.

```
static void Main()
{
    #if DEBUG
        UrlWatcherService service = new UrlWatcherService();
        service.OnDebug();
    #else
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new UrlWatcherService()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    #endif
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this answers your case but worth reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100751/start-winforms-application-from-windows-service

Comment: I added some more comments/code. What boggles me if the article is true is why does the Form show when it's in DEBUG mode?

Comment: Apart from the show problem, (this is no more possible starting from Vista)  I wish to understand why do you need this interaction to happen everytime the service starts. How do you plan to manage this interaction if your service starts when there is no desktop at all? Perhaps it is better to provide a separate application that could stop your service, asks for configuration and restarts the service.

Comment: please see my answer. I solved it properly now, thanks to your hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK due to Steve's hint, I split the projects up. I use a merged module as per [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw2dz878(v=vs.80).aspx), and instead of referencing the GUI in the Service project, I separated them so I can put both their project outputs in the merged module. I then add the merged module to my installer and now I have the service running after install and the ability to call the form from my start menu. It's not what I originally wanted, but a very plausible alternative.

Thanks for Steve for the hint.